# Retrieving array of ids in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

how do you retrieve an array of `IDs` in `Mongoid`?

```
arr=["id1","id2"]
User.where(:id=>arr)
```

You can do this easily if you are retrieving another attribute

```
User.where(:nickname.in=>["kk","ll"])
```

But I am wondering how to do this in mongoid -> this should be a very simple and common operation

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Remember that the ID is stored as `:_id` and not `:id` . There is an `id` helper method, but when you do queries, you should use `:_id`:

```
User.where(:_id.in => arr)
```

Often I find it useful to get a list of ids to do complex queries, so I do something like:

```
user_ids = User.only(:_id).where(:foo => :bar).distinct(:_id)
Post.where(:user_id.in => user_ids)
```

Comment: The solution above works fine when amount of users is small. But it will require a lot of memory while there are thousands of users.

Comment: @dpaluy you are right--this approach is only a hack. Also, the data can change between the first and second queries, especially when there are a lot of documents. Use with caution, or better yet, figure out a better way!

Comment: The better way is to use `.distinct(:_id)` instead of `.map(&:_id)`. `distinct` works during executing the query which is slightly faster than telling rails to loop the array

Answer (score 5):

Or simply:

```
arr = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
User.find(arr)
```

Comment: Issue with above: If just one id is not found, it will return error and not the ids that were found.

Comment: `Mongoid.raise_not_found_error = false` will avoid document not found error raised on above query

Answer (score 4):

The above method suggested by browsersenior doesn't seem to work anymore, at least for me. What I do is:

```
User.criteria.id(arr)
```

Comment: Just a quick note. With Mongoid 2.0.0 and later, you will need to use `for_ids` instead of `id` like so: `User.criteria.for_ids(arr)`

Answer (score 2):

```
user_ids = User.only(:_id).where(:foo => :bar).map(&:_id)
Post.where(:user_id.in => user_ids)
```

The solution above works fine when amount of users is small. But it will require a lot of memory while there are thousands of users.

```
User.only(:_id).where(:foo => :bar).map(&:_id)
```

will create a list of User objects with nil in each field except id.

The solution (for mongoid 2.5):

```
User.collection.master.where(:foo => :bar).to_a.map {|o| o['_id']}
```