# Retrieve list of mongo documents by ids preserving order

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Which is the best way to retrieve a list of mongodb documents using mongoid in the order specified in the list.

My current solution is:

```
docs = Doc.where(:_id.in => ids).sort { |x, y| ids.index(x.id) <=> ids.index(y.id) }
```

It seems there should be a better solution for this using mongoid query interface. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If the number of ids is small you might get away with this (no need to sort it though):

```
docs = ids.map { |id| Doc.find(id) }
```

The drawback is of course that it will still go to the database for every document.

The closest method I could find is `Doc.criteria.for_ids(ids)` but it will not honor the order of the ids and fetch every document only once. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386700/retrieving-array-of-ids-in-mongoid).