# Mongoid - Get Children of Children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Let's assume I have a `grandparent` document with many `parents`, and each `parent` has many `children`.

What is the best way, in Rails with Mongoid, to get all of the `children` for a specific `grandparent` without looping?

For example, if I were to use loops, it would look something like this (rough code):

```
  def children
    children = []
    parents.each do |p|
      p.children.each do |c|
        children << c
      end
    end
    children.uniq
  end

class Grandparent
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :parents
end

class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :grandparent
  has_many :children
end

class Child
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Comment: 'Best' has to be defined in terms of your purpose. Are you optimizing for performance, readability, modularity, or what specifically?

Comment: @Mustafa Performance.

Answer (score 0):

A method like this, it would load the `children` as an attribute once called.

```
def children(reload=false)
   @children = nil if reload
   @children ||= Child.where(:parent_id.in =>  parents.map(&:id))
end
```

See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386700/retrieving-array-of-ids-in-mongoid) as well

Comment: This returns nil: `children = Child.where(:parent_id.in => parents.map(&:id))`, but the looping example in my question works.

Comment: @James it would help if you post the model files showing how the associations are defined.

Comment: @tihorn added to the original question.

Comment: @James give it another try, changed from `:id` to `:_id` in `map`. Also added a reference question with similar answer.

Comment: @tihorn, I am so embarrassed. I was testing this with `rspec` and my factories were being built but not created. Since they weren't in the database, calling `Child.where` would return `nil` because, well, none of the `children` had been saved.

Comment: So to be clear, this is what worked: `Child.where(:parent_id.in => parents.map(&:id))`

Comment: It should work according to the answer you linked.

I am finding that this is profiling quite slow, though.
`| #children           | 55.766 ms | 683.727 ms | 369.746 ms   | 739.493 ms | 2` where 55 is the min, 683 is the max, and 369 is the average.

Comment: to speed it up you can add an index on child table for parent_id